# Dafny 3.0 C# dll library problem from 3.0 to 3.2

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, code-generation, dllimport, dafny

The problem I have is the following: we have a series of functions, methods and datatypes in Dafny and with it we generate a c# dll library. In order to make use of those libraries, we have added them as a reference to a visual studio c# console application project.

[image: Using Dll generated from Dafny 3.0]

The problem I have is that these libraries refer to a dependency to System.Private.CoreLib. The only place I have found this library is in the source code of dafny. By adding it as a reference, it becomes "incompatible" with all System.* libraries imported by default in c#. This makes it unable to create a class, method etc. Attached are screenshots of the problems I just mentioned.

[image: Adding reference to System.Private.CoreLib]

Finally, if I compile these libraries with Dafny 2.0 (deprecated), I don't have this problem, but I would like to work with the latest version of dafny.

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: [System.Private.CoreLib](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/tree/master/src/System.Private.CoreLib) is part of the .NET Core runtime and doesn't have to be referenced directly. That's where the basic built-in types like Array and DateTime live. Which .NET runtime are you targeting? .NET Old? .NET Core? I doubt any Microsoft Research project would target .NET Old in 2021

Answer (score 1):

[System.Private.CoreLib](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/tree/master/src/System.Private.CoreLib) is part of the .NET Core runtime and doesn't have to be referenced directly. That's where the basic built-in types like Array, DateTime, Thread etc live. It's used implicitly by all .NET Core projects and doesn't have to be referenced explicitly.

The [Dafny 3.0](https://github.com/dafny-lang/dafny/releases/tag/v3.0.0) release notes explain that the tooling migrated to .NET (Core) 5 from Mono and the .NET 5 version of Coco/R is used now

> **Tool**
>
> - Migrate to .NET 5.0.
>
> If you used to use mono Dafny.exe to run Dafny before, use dotnet Dafny.dll now.

> **Implementation**
>
> - Use .NET 5.0 version of Coco/R.

Your projects will have to target .NET (Core) 5 as well.

Comment: I've installed Visual Studio 2017, Installed .Net 5.0 and create a console project that use this framework. And the problem is still there. I don't know if could be that I didn't configured well or if there is another problem. The message is still the same : 
The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to the assembly 'System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e

Comment: VS 2017 doesn't support .NET 5 and doesn't even offer the option to target it. .NET 5 was released in 2020, so even if there was a targeting pack for VS 2017 you'd have to deal with compatibility issues. Use the latest version of VS 2019 instead, or work from the command line, using eg VS Code as an IDE.

Comment: I was wrong sorry, the version I've just installed is 2019. 2017 was used when I wrote the original question.

Comment: does somebody have any idea?